# Android Navigation Drawer is overwriting my main layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I recently added a Navigation Drawer to my Android layout. The Drawer itself is working fine, however the old layout is not displaying at all (the elements are there, but not visable).

I have tried to play around with the positioning of the elements, but nothing seems to work.

This is my Layout:

```
<!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
     space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/container" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:background="#FFFFFF">
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:id="@+id/displayframe"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/Content"/>



        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="#AAAAAA"
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"/>

        <ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/listview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#1399cb"

            android:layout_weight="1"
            />

        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
            android:background="#1399cb"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/footer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="#1399cb"
            android:gravity="center" >


        </RelativeLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
 <fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:name="schoolbus.tracker.datavoice.schoolbusdrawer.NavigationDrawerFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
    />   
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

This is the navigation drawer fragment:

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
android:divider="@android:color/black" android:dividerHeight="0dp"
android:background="#cccc" tools:context=".NavigationDrawerFragment"
/>
```

and the layout I use to inflate it:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="#1399cb"
tools:context=".MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

<ImageView android:id="@+id/icons" android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:contentDescription="" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
    android:textSize="19dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/icons"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icons"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/icons" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: use layout_gravity:start

Comment: Actually <ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" this is not fragment it's layout for the fragment if I understand right? In this case I can't see how you use your fragment as navigation drawer and why use separate fragment for navigation drawer?

Comment: I initially used layout_gravity:start, however it did not make a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't go like this:

main activity layout

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#111"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

[Drawer](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)

then in your activity just add fragment to content_frame and that's it:

```
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragmentToShow)
            .commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you haven't closed your FrameLayout inside this layout file,nevertheless i can't see any mistake placed except for that.

EDITED: You must put your frameLayout inside the LinearLayout

```
<!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
                     space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->

<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:id="@+id/displayframe">

    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/container" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:background="#FFFFFF">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/Content"/>
        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="#AAAAAA"
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"/>

        <ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/listview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#1399cb"

            android:layout_weight="1"
            />

        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
            android:background="#1399cb"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/footer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="#1399cb"
            android:gravity="center" >
            </RelativeLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Also Is there any type of rendering problem when you compile it?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the </Frame layout> wasnt showing for some reason, it is present however. i have tried both on the emulator as well as my nexus 4. but its the same for both.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it still isnt displaying. I think the only way to sort this out is to start from scratch.